# Why can any orthogonal matrix be written as $O=e^A$?

Tags: matrices, rotations, orthogonal-matrices, matrix-exponential

I read in the book Quantum Field Theory in a Nutshell that any orthogonal **real** matrix $O$, can be written as $O=e^A$.

I should clarify that 
$O \in \textrm{SO}(N)$, so $O^TO=1$ and $\det (O)=1$

I wonder why this is true and if there's a simple proof?

Comment: [Relevant wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm_of_a_matrix).

Comment: It was relevant but I don't think it was any proof.

Comment: No, but now you know that what you're loking for is called "matrix logarithm". It could give you something to search for if nothing else.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Edit** Since this answer was first written, OP has amended the question to include the conditions that $O \in \operatorname{SO}(n, \Bbb R)$ (that is, $O$ is not only orthogonal but real and special orthgonal). The answer as written does not assume that condition holds but does treat it as a special case.

---

If the matrices are assumed real, this is not true. For any real $n \times n$ matrix $A$, $$\det e^A = e^{\operatorname{tr} A} > 0 ,$$ whereas there are orthogonal matrices with negative determinant, e.g., $I_{n - 1} \oplus \pmatrix{-1}$.

On the other hand, the statement is true if we replace "orthogonal" with "special orthogonal", that is, if we also ask that our orthogonal matrix $O$ satisfy $\det O > 0$ (and hence $\det O = 1$). One can check that the group $\operatorname{SO}(n, \Bbb R)$ of special orthogonal matrices is connected and compact, so [any special orthogonal matrix is the exponential of some matrix $A$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1089636/exponential-map-is-surjective-for-compact-connected-lie-group). In fact, any such $A$ is skew-symmetric, and for any skew-symmetric $A$ the matrix $e^A$ is (special) orthogonal.

On the other hand, if the matrices are assumed complex, even more is true: [For any invertible complex matrix $B$ (and hence for any comple orthogonal matrix) there is a complex matrix $A$ such that $B = e^A$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1242986/proving-that-the-matrix-exponential-map-is-surjective-onto-the-general-linear-gr)

Again, if $A$ is a skew-symmetric complex matrix then $\exp A$ is orthogonal, but not all complex orthgonal matrices arise this way: $\exp$ is continuous, and so the image of the (connected) space of complex skew-symmetric matrices under that map is connected in the standard topology, but the Lie group of complex orthogonal matrices has two connected components. On the other hand, for any complex *special* orthogonal matrix $O$ there is a complex skew-symmetric matrix $A$ such that $O = e^A$, and for any complex skew-symmetric matrix $A$ the matrix $e^A$ is special orthogonal.

Comment: If the matrix has negative determinant, you nevertheless have a representation $O = e^A$ with a complex matrix $A$ such that $A^* = -A$.

Comment: I seem to remember a lot of fuss being made about whether or not there is an $A$ which generates a semigroup of linear operators $\{U_a\}_a$ via $U_a = e^{aA}$. I suspect this is the correct place to look for claims of exponential representation. Nonetheless I would have (naively) assumed such a representation existed for *any* orthogonal group. Does it fail in this case because $A\mapsto e^A$ defines a connected group and $O(n)$ is not connected?

Comment: The context of this claim is that it was found in a QFT book. The matrices are almost certainly complex .

Comment: @SZN That's essentially correct, but NB the image of the space of complex matrices under $\exp$ is the full group $\operatorname{GL}(n, \Bbb C)$, so the story is different in the complex case.

Comment: @Spencer Yes, you're probably right. I've expanded the answer to explain the complex case, too.

Comment: $O$ is a real matrix, and since it belongs to $\textrm{SO}(N)$ it follows that $A$ is real and antisymmetric.