# Show that $H =\operatorname{GL}_n(\Bbb C)$, and $\phi(M_n(\Bbb C))$ generates $\operatorname{GL}_n(\Bbb C)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, group-theory, connectedness

The map $\phi\colon M_n(\mathbb C) \to\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb C)$ is given by $\phi(A) = e^A$ for fixed $n\in \mathbb N$.

> **Part $1$**. Show that there exists an open set $U\subset M_n(\Bbb C)$ containing $\mathbf 0_n$, and an open set $V \subset\operatorname{GL}_n(\Bbb C)$ containing $I_n$, such that (i) for all $A\in U$, $\phi(A) \in V$ (ii) the restriction map $\phi: U\to V$ is bijective, and (iii) both $\phi, \phi^{-1}$ are $C^\infty$.

I have solved Part 1 above.

> **Part $2$**. Let $H$ be $\langle V\rangle$, the subgroup of $\operatorname{GL}_n(\Bbb C)$ generated by $V$. Show that $H = \operatorname{GL}_n(\Bbb C)$. Finally, show that $\phi(M_n(\Bbb C)) \subset\operatorname{GL}_n(\Bbb C)$ generates the group $\operatorname{GL}_n(\Bbb C)$.

**Question**. We have $H = \langle V\rangle \subset\operatorname{GL}_n(\Bbb C)$. As $\operatorname{GL}_n(\Bbb C)$ is connected (in fact, it is path-connected), my intuition is to show that $H$ is both open and closed in $GL_n(\Bbb C)$ - which would ensure $H =\operatorname{GL}_n(\Bbb C)$, since $H \ne \varnothing$. How should I do this?

To show that $\phi(M_n(\Bbb C))$ generates (and actually equals, since the map is surjective) $\operatorname{GL}_n(\Bbb C)$, the linked question (by @orangeskid) contains a proof.

Any help and hints would be greatly appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Comment: "I hope you enjoy solving the problem!" Actually, this has already been solved :) Which book are you using? A proof might be in [Warner](https://d-nb.info/840275498/04), for example.

Comment: In the case of $GL(n, \mathbb{C})$ the maps is in fact surjective. This is not true for every  connected groups, but the other properties still hold.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I couldn't find it. Perhaps you could help?

Comment: @orangeskid I see - how do you prove the surjectivity? In any case, there are also other aspects of the problem, especially the application of the inverse function theorem, which I need help with. Could you drop any hints?

Comment: surjectivity proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1242986/proving-that-the-matrix-exponential-map-is-surjective-onto-the-general-linear-gr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An open subgroup $H$ of a topological group $G$ is also closed. Indeed, $G$ can be written as the disjoint union $G= \bigcup _{a\in G/H} a.H$. But all the terms in this disjoint union are open, and $H ^c= \bigcup _{a\in G/H, a\not = H} a.H$, thus $H^c$ is open.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The fact that $H = \langle V\rangle$ is open follows from $H = \bigcup_{g\in \langle V\rangle} gV$ right? Then using your argument, $H$ is also closed. Therefore, $H$ being non-empty, is equal to $GL_n(\Bbb C)$.