# Is the exponential map of a complex unital Banach algebra surjective onto the set of (two-sidedly) invertible elements?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-algebras

Let $A$ be a complex unital Banach algebra, and let $A^\times$ denote the set of (two-sidedly) invertible elements of $A$. Let $\exp : A \rightarrow A^\times$ denote the exponential map.

My question is, in general is the exponential map surjective onto $A^\times$?

What I understand so far is as follows:

- If we replace "complex" with "real", then the answer becomes no. E.g. we can take $A$ to be $\mathbb{R}$ itself, or more generally the matrix algebra $\mathrm{Mat}_n(\mathbb{R})$ for any integer $n>0$. [(reference)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/200743/non-surjectivity-of-the-exponential-map-to-gl2-r)
- The answer becomes "yes" in the case $A = \mathrm{Mat}_n(\mathbb{C})$, for integer $n>0$. [(reference)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1242986/proving-that-the-matrix-exponential-map-is-surjective-onto-the-general-linear-gr)

However I'm not sure how to generalize the 2nd bullet point, nor how to find a counter-example. Would anyone have any suggestions on how to think about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the algebra of continuous complex-valued functions on $S^1\subset\mathbb C$ (with the sup-norm). The identity function is not exp of any continuous function, so the answer is no.

In general, such questions are answered using the holomophic calculus for Banach algebras.

Answer (score 1):

The set of invertible elements $G(A)$ is an open subset of $A$. $\exp(A)$ is precisely the connected component of the unit $1\in A$. Thus, if $G(A)$ is connected, then $G(A) = \exp(A)$. Otherwise, define an equivalence relation on $G(A)$ by $$x\sim y \Leftrightarrow xy^{-1}\in\exp(A).$$ Let $\{x_{\alpha}\exp(A) : \alpha\in J\}$ denote the set of equivalence classes of $\sim$. These equivalence classes are precisely the (open) connected components of $G(A)$.

For the two examples you've provided:

1. If $A=M(\mathbb{C}^n)$ then $G(A)$ is connected.
2. If $A=M(\mathbb{R}^n)$ then $G(A)$ has two connected components; $\exp(A) = \{x\in A: \det(x)>0\}$ and $\{x\in A: \det(x)<0\}$